# ng-otp-input doesn't support well with input 0

Tags: angular6

I used `ng-otp-input npm` and it does not move/focus on next text box while I enter 0 in textbox.

I have tried :

```
<ng-otp-input (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="config">
</ng-otp-input>

config = {
 allowNumbersOnly: false,
 length: 4,
 inputStyles: {
  'color': 'white',
  'width': '30px',
  'height': '50px',
  'border': 'none',
  'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the version issue. I suggest you to remove this npm and install new updated version.