# Ng serve: Getting error while compiling (ng serve)

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

`enter code here`ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 32:149-167
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modu`

```js
{
  "name": "jugnoo-user-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^12.4.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "12.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.20.3",
    "angular-crypto-js": "^1.0.7",
    "angular-http-server": "^1.10.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.13",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.8.1",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.3.0",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^9.3.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

`les/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 232:190-208
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 252:165-183
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 34:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 234:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 261:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 233:46-69
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareComponent' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 32:35-56
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-otp-input/fesm2015/ng-otp-input.js 232:46-67

i tried ng serve command in local terminal but while compiling it throws an error.

I have tried unistall npm angular and reinstall them and clone my app in different folder

Comment: What is the node and npm version ?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57114140/8197738) 
[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65693339/8197738)
questions looks having same issues raised.

Comment: @BarunGhosh node version: 16.15.1 and npm version : 8.19.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check whether you have compatible versions of angular and node. The compatibility matrix can be found here https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall it and reinstall it again through `npm install --save ng-otp-input@1.8.1` because the `1.8.1` version is the version for older angular versions (V12 and below) according to its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/code-farmz/ng-otp-input#for-older-angular-version-use-v181).